# "zsh: command not found: $" // can't install anything on terminal

Tags: command, zsh

zsh: command not found: $

Every time I try to install anything or run anything on my terminal I get this message. I am using a MacBook air m1, macOS Monterey. Does anyone know how to fix?

Comment: You did not say which command you issued to get this error message.

Answer (score 0):

The last time my commands got crazy I were changed my path and forgot to reassign the old value, thus, my commands did not run. Try:

```
echo $PATH
```

Possibly if you have any issue with your PATH variable you can see it.